# Python multiprocessing with print() doesn't work

Tags: python, printing, multiprocessing, daemon

I'm learning multiprocessing with python and it doesn't seem to work with the `print()` function and IDLE's shell.

Also, making a process as Daemon doesn't seems to work either as the process doesn't get killed when the Main program ends.

here is the code I wrote, I hope some1 could explain what could be wrong:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def proc1(x):                                    # Creates a function to be used inside a process
    for i in range(x):
        print("proc1 is running")       # It seems like the Child Processes doesn't print the "print()" function into the IDLE's shell

if __name__ == '__main__':              # Important!!! we dont want to create endless subprocesses by mistake
    
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(name='proc of Python' , target=proc1 , args=[300000])
    proc.daemon = True                  # make the process a Daemon and get killed with the end of the Main Program   - doesn't seems to work in this example, I can see the process keep running on Task Manager
    proc2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='proc2 of Python' , target=proc1 , args=[300000])
    proc2.start()  
    proc.start()
 #   proc.join()
    print('Multi Processing is hard!!\n\n')
```

Comment: Are you using IDLE? , for me I don't get the output of "proc1 is running", and the "proc" Object doesn't terminate after the Main program finishes , it just keep running for ever if you give the function args=[30000000000] for example

Comment: IDLE will only capture the output of the process it starts.  But if you execute the script inside a terminal, all the print output will be shown in the terminal. Also you have used same callback for the two processes, how do you know which process that the print output is coming from?  My result (after passing the id of the proc to `proc1()` and print the id in `proc1()` as well) is that `proc` is never started whereas `proc2` is started.  However if `time.sleep(x)` (x is long enough) is added at the end of the script, both processes are started.

Comment: So IDLE has its own problems, that could explain the issue.  you say that `proc` didn't start for you and this is because it is a Daemon process that should be terminated with the main script while `proc2` shouldn't  - this result is what I was looking for in my experiment but instead the `proc` process kept running in the backround and didn't got terminated (in Task Manager)

Comment: After running the program directly , and not using the IDLE's shell , I can see that the program works and the process `proc` is also being terminated when the main program finish , I guess IDLE doesn't support multiprocessing in a bit